# How to detect a glove finger defect in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

[image]

How should I detect whether a defect (as seen in the above image - this is called a 'Tie down error') is present in a finger of the glove?

I have already extracted each finger tip (using contours and contour approximation) and the algorithm can identify if the shape of the glove is not perfect.

[image]

But it does not detect a tie down at the tip of the glove finger.

[image]

How can I detect this using OpenCV?

Comment: did you try counting edges of the contour?

Comment: I did. Most of the time I get an edge (at the tip) even if the tip is folded.

Comment: An apparent feature that distinguish defect is its intensity.You can try to threshold at different levels and if binary version is not a perfect shape,it is a defiency.But this is a very simple and can fail on most conditions.You should find distiungishing features of defiency and use them . If you have large data of gloves both perfect and broken ones,you may try to use a machine learning algorithm. BUT this is a complex and very specific case,you can not find a predefined method for this,you should create your own.

Comment: can you add examples of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment each finger and then apply to each finger an analysis based on color or grey level: a good finger has almost the same grey level/color while a defective one has a dark part.

In order to segment the fingers: for each finger found the landmarks: **B1** (base 1), **B2** (base 2) and **T** (tip); see them in purple in the below image.

[image]

It seems to me that you already have these landmarks because you draw the blue graphics.

Once you have them you define a region with these boundaries: the straight line between **B1** and **B2** and the red contour you already have (the red contour you draw here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXfoC.jpg ) starting from **B1** and going to **B2** through **T**.

[image]

Then you apply for each region your analysis, for example mark as defective all the pixel with intensity below a threshold.